# lua string.match does't match as expected(different with other language)

Tags: lua

```
a = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
print(string.match(a,"(.*/)"))   -- stackoverflow.com/questions/
print(string.match(a,"(.*/).*")) -- stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

I can't understand the second result. In my option it should be "`stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`" as "`(.*/)`" matches "`stackoverflow.com/questions/`" and "`.*`" matches "`ask`". Can someone tell me WHY the second result is  "`stackoverflow.com/questions/`" ? Does `x = string.match(a,"(.*/).*")` and `x = string.match(a,"(.*/)")` are same?

Comment: So why do you think it should be "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"? Please refer the [ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Because `string.match(a,"(.*/).*")` returns the capture instead of the whole match.  Try `string.match(a,"((.*/).*)")` to get two captures.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Got it. I have a  new question now.I saw someone's Lua code like this: `x = string.match(a,"(.*/).*")`. Does it has any difference with `x = string.match(a,"(.*/)")` ?

Comment: if you have a new question, open a new question. that's not what comments are for... also what stops you from just trying if there is any difference? you know starting the Lua interpreter is for free!

Comment: @hcch - `string.match(a,"(.*/).*")` is the same as `string.match(a,"(.*/)")`. But with `string.gsub` these patterns will behave differently.

Comment: @Piglet I have already tried many times and found they are same. But as the code was found in a famous open source project, I have to doubt if it has other meaning by add `.*`. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you very much!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - Sorry, I'm too lazy.  :-)  Maybe someone else would write complete answer to earn rep points.

Answer (score 1):

the () means you have used Captures.so maybe you can use it like this:

```
print(string.match(a,"((.*/).*)"))
```

[Captures:](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)

A pattern can contain sub-patterns enclosed in parentheses; they describe captures. When a match succeeds, the substrings of the subject string that match captures are stored (captured) for future use. Captures are numbered according to their left parentheses. For instance, in the pattern "(a*(.)%w(%s*))", the part of the string matching "a*(.)%w(%s*)" is stored as the first capture (and therefore has number 1); the character matching "." is captured with number 2, and the part matching "%s*" has number 3.